# Trying to locate the number of hits within a range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So basically I have a spreadsheet with numerous dates/times formatted as "1/17/2013  10:38:26 AM"  with several hundred results.  Basically what I need to be able to due is determine overlapping times based on the assumption that each time runs a duration of 2 minutes.  so for instance if there was "1/17/2013  10:38:26 AM", "1/17/2013  10:39:26 AM", and "1/17/2013  10:39:36 AM" it would say three.  Essentially throughout all the times listed for a given day I need to know the max number of calls occurring during a 2 minute time period.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Any luck on the proposed solutions?

Answer (score 0):

For Excel 2007+, have a look at [Countifs()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx).  For Excel 2003 and below, you would need [Sumproduct()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/mac-excel-help/sumproduct-function-HA102928053.aspx?CTT=1).  See [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-numbers-or-dates-based-on-a-test-HP010342341.aspx?CTT=1) for an example that applies to your question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your times are in one column, this should work for you:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ABS($A$2:$A$13-A2)<=1/1440)*(1))
```

[image: example]

Give it a shot.

Comment: This includes itself as a time - sounds like you wanted that - you would just do a minus one on it if you wanted to exclude itself.